# Как обработать текст? Python

Tags: python

Не могу текст (str) видом:

```
('Фомин Дмитрий Петрович', '1111111111'), ('Лисенко Дмитрий', '2222222222'), ('Родриго Дмитрий Сергеевич', '3333333333'), и так далее
```

НЕ циклом вывести его  с каждой новой строки, а так же без скобок и запятых вывести чистым видом.

Если без цикла никак, то уже пусть будет циклом, просто мне надо одним сообщением в телеграмм боте отправить, а не куча отдельных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если тебе нужно вывести в формате "элемент1.1 элемент1.2\nэлемент2.1 элемент2.2", то есть самый наивный вариант: сформировать строку, которую ты потом отправишь

```py
arr = [('Фомин Дмитрий Петрович', '1111111111'), ('Лисенко Дмитрий', '2222222222'), ('Родриго Дмитрий Сергеевич', '3333333333')]

final_str = ""

for item in arr:
    final_str += item[0] + " " + item[1] + "\n"
```

Вывод

```
Фомин Дмитрий Петрович 1111111111
Лисенко Дмитрий 2222222222
Родриго Дмитрий Сергеевич 3333333333
```

Comment: всё сработало, то как нужно, лучший!